# Force stop php script execution

Tags: php, while-loop, long-polling

I am trying to code a Long Polling Server script. I am in problems now. For some reason, the php file where the poll is exceuted never stop. Never.

```
$timeout = 9000000; //9 sec
$wait = 3000000; //3 sec
$now = time();
$lastAccess = $db->getLastAccess();

while( $lastAccess <= $now && 0 < $timeout) {

    usleep($wait); //wait 3 secs

    //decrease limit
    $timeout = $timeout - $wait;

    writeLog("\n\n Checking last access...\n\n");
    $lastAccess = $db->getLastAccess();


    if (0 >= $timeout)
        writeLog("\n\n timeout on server...\n\n");

}

//return whatever
```

I tried to use `$timeout` and `$wait` vars to eventually force to break the while loop. However, if I do `tail -f error.log` (where the logs messages are been written) looks like this php file is always in execution! I would like to know how I could stop the php file execution after certaint among of time.

*Edit: if a new "event" arrives, it stop successfully.

Comment: Use `break;` statement

Comment: Using the break into the timeout if statements does not difference. Also, the while should make the trick cause the `$timeout` is been decresed for each iteration.

Comment: Add a `writeLog` call after the end of the loop to see if you're breaking out.

Comment: @Barmar, it is getting confused: I have put `writeLog('end of file')` and it is never call!

Comment: Seems like problem with `$lastAccess`. Try to see what are its return values. Do you want to stop the loop after 3 seconds?

Comment: Ok, the problemas was about cache. I have put `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");` and then restart the web server. Now is working :)